# c# parse datetime "Fri Jan 14 2011 14:56:36 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm doing

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz zzzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But, that is generating an error (the error was that date was not in the correct format). Do you guys know what the correct syntax is?

The date is:

> Fri Jan 14 2011 15:00:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

Comment: The error was that date was not in the correct format.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work if you strip the end of the string.

```
var stringDate = "Fri Jan 14 2011 15:00:39 GMT-0800";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
        stringDate,
        "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Fri Jan 14 2011 15:00:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` what is contained in your time string?  If so, your format mask or your input string is incorrect.  Please refer to the MSDN library.

This sample is taken from the [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
// Parse date and time with custom specifier.
//            Fri Jan 14 2011 15:00:39 GMT-0800
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
try {
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

If I had to take a guess, you are not providing the correct time zone format.