# converting string of datetime to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert a string of `date-time` to `date-time format` like this **5/10/2016 12:00:00 AM**  format . I tried more than way but not working please any advice.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtManufacturerDate.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy",null);
```

Comment: Have you checked other questions here on SO? E. g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696872/c-sharp-parse-datetime-fri-jan-14-2011-145636-gmt-0800-pacific-standard-time

Comment: Did you using Convert.ToDateTime(string)

Comment: Well, you've got slashes and a time in your string, and hyphens and no time in your exact format string, so you might want to look at that first...

Comment: please take a look at the [MSDN DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(v=vs.110).aspx) also you can google how to use the `Convert.ToDateTime(string variable)`

Comment: @techspider yes i did

Comment: Where is the string you are trting convert ***from***? Anyway, I expect format to be wrong.

Comment: @JoeEnos, it's date in format he wants to get. Not in format he has.

Comment: @Qwertiy this is the format 5/10/2016 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @hashim, then you want to convert string to date and than back to the same string?

Comment: so something like this you're saying you tried and didn't work?
`string sDate = "5/10/2016";
 var newDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate);`

Comment: @MethodMan i want to convert string of date to date-time only and the format of the date i want to convert is 5/10/2016 12:00:00 AM

Comment: why don't you run the code and you will see that it yields DateTime from the string are you familiar with how to use the debugger.. ? run that in a Console app and you will see

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtManufacturerDate.Text).ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: it should be ToDateTime

Comment: Just use Convert.ToDateTime(txtManufacturerDate.Text)

Comment: @SufyanJabr before posting an answer one would think that it would `Compile for starters` there is no `.ToDate` function in C# it's `.ToDateTime` also if you are going to suggest a fix for your code in a comment why not just update the answer so you won't get downvoted for incorrect syntax how can code that doesn't compile be marked as an acceptable answer.. LOL